# Show in ListBox.Text an XML file content

Tags: c#, xml, path, listbox

I started today work with XML file in C# and I really don't know how to make this task.

I have this XML:

```xml
<Units>
  <Unit>
    <UNIT_NAME>First</UNIT_NAME>
    <SRC>
        <SRC_NAME>a</SRC_NAME>
            <SUB_SRC_NAME>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>i_first_srt_alfa</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>i_first_srt_beta</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
            </SUB_SRC_NAME>
        <SRC_NAME>b</SRC_NAME>
            <SUB_SRC_NAME>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>alfa</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>beta</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
            </SUB_SRC_NAME>
    </SRC>
    <DOC>
        <DOC_NAME>i_first_doc</DOC_NAME>
            <SUB_DOC_NAME>
                    <SUB_DOC_NAME_A>alfa</SUB_DOC_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_DOC_NAME_A>beta</SUB_DOC_NAME_A>
            </SUB_DOC_NAME> 
    </DOC>
    <TST>
        <TST_NAME>i_first_tst</TST_NAME>
            <SUB_TST_NAME>
                    <SUB_TST_NAME_A>alfa</SUB_TST_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_TST_NAME_A>beta</SUB_TST_NAME_A>
            </SUB_TST_NAME> 
    </TST>  
  </Unit>
  <Unit>
    <UNIT_NAME>Second</UNIT_NAME>
    <SRC>
        <SRC_NAME>c</SRC_NAME>
            <SUB_SRC_NAME>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>alfa</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>beta</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
            </SUB_SRC_NAME>
        <SRC_NAME>d</SRC_NAME>
            <SUB_SRC_NAME>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>alfa</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_SRC_NAME_A>beta</SUB_SRC_NAME_A>
            </SUB_SRC_NAME>
    </SRC>
    <DOC>
        <DOC_NAME>i_first_doc</DOC_NAME>
            <SUB_DOC_NAME>
                    <SUB_DOC_NAME_A>i_first_doc_alfa</SUB_DOC_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_DOC_NAME_A>i_first_doc_beta</SUB_DOC_NAME_A>
            </SUB_DOC_NAME> 
    </DOC>
    <TST>
        <TST_NAME>i_first_tst</TST_NAME>
            <SUB_TST_NAME>
                    <SUB_TST_NAME_A>i_first_tst_alfa</SUB_TST_NAME_A>
                    <SUB_TST_NAME_A>i_first_tst_beta</SUB_TST_NAME_A>
            </SUB_TST_NAME> 
    </TST>  
  </Unit>
</Units>
```

And I want to show in a listbox in the following format:

```
First 
First -- a 
First -- b
Second 
Second -- c 
Second -- d
```

This is my current code:

```cs
XmlNodeList xnUnitList = xml.SelectNodes("/Units/Unit");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnUnitList)
{
    string UNIT_NAME = xn["UNIT_NAME"].InnerText;
    listBox1.Items.Add(UNIT_NAME);
    XmlNodeList SRC =xn.SelectNodes("/Units/Unit/SRC");
    foreach (XmlNode node in SRC)
    {
        string SRC_NAME = node["SRC_NAME"].InnerText;
        listBox1.Items.Add(UNIT_NAME+"--" +SRC_NAME);
    }
}
```

But the outcome shows like this

```
First
First -- a
First -- c
Second
Second -- a
Second -- c
```

Why do those `a` and `c` appear again and why are `b` and `d` missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to traverse the children of a Node. If you want to do that you shouldn't use an XPath expression that considers all Nodes in the document again.

In your `xn.SelectNodes("/Units/Unit/SRC");` you're attempting to select the `SRC` node children of the `xn` node. But instead you're telling `SelectNodes` to forget all that and instead start selecting nodes from the root again.

Two small changes fix your code:

```
XmlNodeList xnUnitList = xml.SelectNodes("/Units/Unit");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnUnitList)
{
    string UNIT_NAME = xn["UNIT_NAME"].InnerText;
    listBox1.Items.Add(UNIT_NAME);

    // select all Nodes under the current Node 
    // that are a child of SRC
    // and have a name of SRC_NAME
    XmlNodeList SRC =xn.SelectNodes("SRC/SRC_NAME");
    foreach (XmlNode node in SRC)
    {
        // node is now a SRC_NAME so no further 
        // juggling needed, you have what you need
        string SRC_NAME = node.InnerText;
        listBox1.Items.Add(UNIT_NAME+"--" +SRC_NAME);
    }
}
```